# morphia save and ignore some fields

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

My object (myObj) looks like so

```
field1:""
,field2:""
,field3:""
........
,fieldn:""

,otherfield1:""
,otherfield2:""
,otherfield3:""
```

is there a way to do something like

```
db.save(myObj).ignoreFields("otherField1", "otherField2", "otherField3");
```

that way, those 3 fields will be left unchanged during this operation.
Morphia syntax is preferrable, but if such thing is not possible, then mongo java driver syntax is also okay.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario and reason a bit more? If you never want to persist these fields (for example) you can mark them as transient.

Comment: only people with certain permission is allowed to update those fields

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that's a job for your application/business logic to check. By this I mean your code stop check permission before it changes those fields inside your object and let Mongo/Morphia save the entire document.

Your other option is to use MongoDB's update API to $set just the fields you want changed: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Finally - maybe you could refactor to store these secure fields in a separate document in another collection, but this again brings you back to managing permissions in your business logic.